# how do I get org-mode to use smart quotes on HTML export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, smartypants

What's the best way to get org-mode to use smart quotes on HTML export?

Is there a way to use [Smartypants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)?

I added this to my .emacs but it doesn't work.

```
     (setq org-export-html-special-string-regexps
        (cons
         '(" \"\\([^\"]+\\)\"" . " &ldquo;\\1&rdquo;")
         org-export-html-special-string-regexps))
```

Comment: Uh, you asked the same question twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Emacs configuration file:

```
(setq org-export-with-smart-quotes t)
```